# Download a folder, including all files and sub folders, from an FTP Site

Tags: powershell, ftp

I have searched the world over for a Powershell Script that will download a folder, including all files and sub folders, from an FTP Site. Most of them have come from StackOverflow. The problem I am having is that none of them work. All wind up throwing an error of some sort. I don't have the points on StackOverflow to comment or ask questions. Does anybody have one that is known to work?

Comment: You are question [banned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66069863/having-fits-getting-results-from-invoke-webrequest) at Stack Overflow, so sadly this question will probably just be closed, since it's out of scope.  Your inability to post a question on Stack Overflow has to do with your history of asking a question, getting an answer, then deleting it.

Comment: It was not banned at StackOverflow. Read the question. See where it said "I don't have enough points to comment or ask questions"?

Comment: You don't need reputation on Stack Overflow to ask a question on Stack Overflow.  You have asked this very question on Stack Overflow multiple times, except in those cases, you actually provided code.

Comment: When I go under the question that provides a script I cannot add a comment or post cost. That is what I need to be able to do to ask for help on the code. Since I can't do that I am stuck. The question might be a duplicate but when I go to the original question I can't add a comment asking why it doesn't work so using StackOverflow does me no good.

Comment: You can always comment under your own questions. You shouldn't ask questions within a comment to another question's answer anyways.  Like Stack Overflow we need to see the script that doesn't work, the error that is generated, and any research you have performed on the subject.  You were previously provided [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080506/powershell-ftp-download-files-and-subfolders) as a solution to your problem.

Comment: Correct and 1) that did not work and 2) Add comment is greyed out. Then if I copied and pasted the code that didn't work to a new question it gets closed because it is a duplicate question. See the dilemma?

Comment: So what have you tried? Saying what you tried hasn't worked isn't enough.  What you have provided in your Stack Overflow question's isn't enough.  I would expect the code to correct from a syntax point out view at a minimum in order to diagnose it.  We are not a PowerShell script writing service.

Comment: I've asked you for *minimal reproducible example* at your Stack Overflow post and you never provided it.

Comment: I am just going to say never mind. None of the scripts at StackOverflow work and I can't ask questions so it is kind of moot. I really don't believe anyone has come up with a working script and to be honest I have better things to do with my time. I'll try some different forums that aren't so restrictive.

Comment: You do not have to ask a new question. Just edit some of your questions on SO to show *minimal reproducible example*, instead of asking dozen questions without enough information. **It's that simple.** – The code example you were pointed to **works**. If it does not work for you, either you have some very specific problem, or you are doing something wrong. You didn't give us enough information to help you with either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Winscp Powershell assembly. Here is sample code to download all folders under /home/user

$session.add_QueryReceived( {
Write-Host "Error: $($*.Message)"
$*.Continue()
} )

$session.GetFiles("/home/user/*", "d:\download").Check()

Link to Original code.

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_recursive_download_custom_error_handling

Comment: Want to do it with Native Powershell. Thanks.

Comment: @Ziggy32 - Your question makes no mention of that.

Comment: Well... Winscp isn't Powershell. I asked for a method using Powershell.